# sidekiqctl shutdown not working

Tags: sidekiq

I'm trying to shutdown a sidekiq worker with `sidekiqctl`

```
bundle exec sidekiqctl stop /mnt/www/project/shared/pids/sidekiq.pid 20
```

Then I see the message:

```
Sidekiq shut down forcefully.
```

BEFORE running the command, the sidekiq.pid file exists and matches the PID that I can see sidekiq running as.

AFTER running this command, the same sidekiq PID is still running (it didn't shut down). But now the pid file is gone, presumably because sidekiqctl deleted it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out this was a chef/god issue... `sidekiqctl` is working just fine.